# Filter listview rows with radiobutton selection

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I don't understand what wrong I am doing here but my listview is not filtering data as per selection. Once page gets load it gets data according to selected city from master page. That is working but when I apply another filter it doesn't gets changed. On page I have multiple filters.

VB

```
Private Sub hospitals_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    Try
        Dim citySelector As DropDownList = Page.Master.FindControl("locationSelector")
        If Session("masterLocation") Is Nothing Then
            citySelector.Text = "Pune"
        Else
            citySelector.Text = Session("masterLocation").ToString()
        End If

        query = "SELECT hospitalID, name, address, thumbnail, knownFor, mondayFrom, mondayTo, consultancyFees FROM hospitals where city like '" + citySelector.SelectedItem.ToString + "%'"
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 120
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim table As New DataTable
        da.Fill(table)
        ViewState("Data") = table
        hospitals.DataSource = table
        hospitals.DataBind()
        'countItems.Text = String.Format(table.Rows(0)("dataCount"))
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub areasList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles areasList.SelectedIndexChanged
    'locationFilter.Text = areasList.SelectedItem.ToString
    Try
        ViewState("Data") = ""
        If areasList.SelectedValue <> "All" And servicesList.SelectedValue <> "All" And facilitiesList.SelectedValue <> "All" And paymentsList.SelectedValue <> "All" Then
            query = "SELECT * FROM hospitals where address Like '" + areasList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%' and services Like '%" + servicesList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%' and facilities Like '%" + facilitiesList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%'"

        ElseIf areasList.SelectedValue = "All" And servicesList.SelectedValue <> "All" And facilitiesList.SelectedValue <> "All" And paymentsList.SelectedValue <> "All" Then
            query = "SELECT * FROM hospitals where services Like '%" + servicesList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%' and facilities Like '%" + facilitiesList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%' and payment Like '%" + paymentsList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%'"

        ElseIf areasList.SelectedValue <> "All" And servicesList.SelectedValue = "All" And facilitiesList.SelectedValue <> "All" And paymentsList.SelectedValue <> "All" Then
            query = "SELECT * FROM hospitals where areaName Like '%" + areasList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%' and facilities Like '%" + facilitiesList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%' and payment Like '%" + paymentsList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%'"

        ElseIf areasList.SelectedValue <> "All" And servicesList.SelectedValue <> "All" And facilitiesList.SelectedValue = "All" And paymentsList.SelectedValue <> "All" Then
            query = "SELECT * FROM hospitals where areaName Like '%" + areasList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%' and services Like '%" + servicesList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%' and payment Like payment Like '%" + paymentsList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%'"

        ElseIf areasList.SelectedValue <> "All" And servicesList.SelectedValue <> "All" And facilitiesList.SelectedValue <> "All" And paymentsList.SelectedValue = "All" Then
            query = "SELECT * FROM hospitals where areaName Like '%" + areasList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%' and services Like '%" + servicesList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%' and facilities Like '%" + facilitiesList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%'"

        ElseIf areasList.SelectedValue <> "All" And servicesList.SelectedValue = "All" And facilitiesList.SelectedValue = "All" And paymentsList.SelectedValue = "All" Then
            query = "SELECT * FROM hospitals where areaName Like '%" + areasList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%'"

        ElseIf areasList.SelectedValue = "All" And servicesList.SelectedValue <> "All" And facilitiesList.SelectedValue = "All" And paymentsList.SelectedValue = "All" Then
            query = "SELECT * FROM hospitals where services Like '%" + servicesList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%'"

        ElseIf areasList.SelectedValue = "All" And servicesList.SelectedValue = "All" And facilitiesList.SelectedValue <> "All" And paymentsList.SelectedValue = "All" Then
            query = "SELECT * FROM hospitals where facilities Like '%" + facilitiesList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%'"

        ElseIf areasList.SelectedValue = "All" And servicesList.SelectedValue = "All" And facilitiesList.SelectedValue = "All" And paymentsList.SelectedValue <> "All" Then
            query = "SELECT * FROM hospitals where payment Like '%" + paymentsList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%'"

        ElseIf areasList.SelectedValue <> "All" And servicesList.SelectedValue <> "All" And facilitiesList.SelectedValue = "All" And paymentsList.SelectedValue = "All" Then
            query = "SELECT * FROM hospitals where areaName Like '%" + areasList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%' and services Like '%" + servicesList.SelectedItem.ToString + "%'"

        ElseIf areasList.SelectedValue = "All" And servicesList.SelectedValue = "All" And facilitiesList.SelectedValue = "All" And paymentsList.SelectedValue = "All" Then
            query = "SELECT * FROM hospitals WHERE status Like 'Active'"
        End If

        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim table As New DataTable

        da.Fill(table)
        ViewState("Data") = table
        hospitals.DataSource = table
        hospitals.DataBind()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Response.Write(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to debug, let me know what happen.

Comment: I think problem is your PreRender method. As it is being executed every time, when page have been load, it refreshes your list with an old list. So what you may do is just move that code to your Page_Load and input into *if (!IsPostBack)* block (moving to Page_Load method is preferrable)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have depends on where you do things.
There are many problems in your code.
First of all I can suggest to move code on pre rendere in `onload`/`Page_Load`
In that method you have

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
  base.OnLoad(e);  
  // here code executes Always on every onload
  if (Page.IsPostback)
        return;
  // here code executes only first load
  FillCombo();
  SetInitialValues();
  BindSearchResults();
}
```

I also suggest:

1. to move all queries in a class of data layer
2. to prefer zero or "" to "All"
3. to write Status = 'Active' and not like
4. i read many times Page.Master.FindControl("locationSelector"): i think there is a better way to get locationSelector. If it's located in ascx control or in master page, you can change it in public.